# Audit Table - Can we store the new value on audit table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created the audit table similar to the below code which logs the changes made on the source table. My question is can a audit table contain newly inserted record or it should contain only the updated records/history since the new record is there in source table ?

I am Looking for pros/cons on each approach and best practice.

```
create table tblOrders
(
  OrderID integer Identity(1,1) primary key,
  OrderApprovalDateTime datetime,
  OrderStatus varchar(20)
)

create table tblOrdersAudit
(
  OrderAuditID integer Identity(1,1) primary key,
  OrderID integer,
  OrderApprovalDateTime datetime,
  OrderStatus varchar(20),
  UpdatedBy nvarchar(128),
  UpdatedOn datetime
)
go

create trigger tblTriggerAuditRecord on tblOrders
after update, insert
as
begin
  insert into tblOrdersAudit 
  (OrderID, OrderApprovalDateTime, OrderStatus, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn )
  select i.OrderID, i.OrderApprovalDateTime, i.OrderStatus, SUSER_SNAME(), getdate() 
  from  tblOrders t 
  inner join inserted i on t.OrderID=i.OrderID 
end
go
```

Comment: Don't post images of code. Post code as text.

Comment: It depends on what you want to. There can't be 1 answer to this question. If you want to store them all, then store, if you not, then don't store.

Comment: @ibrahimozgon : I am looking for best practice on what audit table suppose to be. Thanks for your answer

Comment: just so you're aware - if you're on a recent version of SQL (2017 or later) then this stuff is built into the database.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally based on your case,
But I would like to have the Audit table to have all records, the new inserted and the updated, so that I can view, check history, do time line calculations,... using just the Audit table as a separate entity without going back to the original table.
Also It might be helpful if I want to roll back to a certain record (it could be the first inserted one)